# Custom equality comparator for set operation in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, collections, intersection, equality

As mentioned here: [Efficient way to compare an partition two collections in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78180749/efficient-way-to-compare-an-partition-two-collections-in-kotlin) I am working on a Kotlin application that needs to compare lists of Json objects. To find the elements that are common between the existing data and the incoming data, I was hoping to use the intersect (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/intersect.html) function. The problem is, my incoming data and existing data are do not contain objects of the same class. They DO have some common fields that I can use to compare them, but I can't see a good way to define the comparison operation for the intersect function. I don't want to override 'equals' in my data classes since I only want to change the equality behaviour for this specific use case.

Is there some way to do this in Kotlin that I'm just not seeing?

Comment: Can you show some examples of your data? If the objects are not of the same class, what does it mean for them to be "equal"? Can you convert the objects you get to a separate data class instead?

Comment: You can look at the implementation of `intersect()` and create your own. As far as I can tell it boils down to `retainOrRemoveAllInternal` which uses `==` to compare elements,  you could implement similar that uses a predicate.

Comment: You're going to need to reimplement it yourself.

Comment: Another option might be to write wrapper classes for your objects, with a suitable equals() implementation, and temporarily wrap your objects before calling intersection().

Answer (score 1):

You could define a class that holds the common fields that you need to be compared:

```
data class CommonFields private constructor(fieldA: Int, fieldB: String) {
    val originalInstanceA: ClassA? = null
    val originalInstanceB: ClassB? = null

    constructor(originalInstanceA: ClassA) : this(
        originalInstanceA.fieldA, originalInstanceA.fieldB
    ) {
        this.originalInstanceA = originalInstanceA
    }

    constructor(originalInstanceB: ClassB) : this(
        originalInstanceB.fieldA, originalInstanceB.fieldB
    ) {
        this.originalInstanceB = originalInstanceB
    }
}
```

Then you can map the two lists:

```
val commonFieldsA = listA.map { CommonFields(it) }
val commonFieldsB = listB.map { CommonFields(it) }
```

And now you can find the intersection:

```
commonFieldsA intersect commonFieldsB
```

The reason this works is that the `equals` method generated for the `data class` uses only those fields in the primary constructor and ignored other fields (the references to the original instances in this case).

Comment: The only real issue I can see with that approach is that you still need to create a wrapper instance for every item in both collections. I THINK that will be OK in this use case since I only expect each collection to be a few thousand items at most. In a more general purpose application with larger datasets however I'm not sure how well this would scale.